# Netbeans: "Run -> Test Project" doesn't do anything

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, junit, netbeans6.8

I have many JUnit tests, which are all created by Netbeans' assistant (so nothing customized). I can run every test **manually** by doing "Test File" (Ctrl+F6).

But when I use "Run -> Test Project", the message "No Tests executed" is displayed.

Do I have to register every JUnit test somewhere?
Or what could be the problem here?

Before that, following appears in the output window:

```
init:
Deleting: /MY-WORK/my.data.adv/build/built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: /MY-WORK/my.data.adv/build/built-jar.properties
my.commons.init:
my.commons.deps-jar:
Updating property file: /MY-WORK/my.data.adv/build/built-jar.properties
my.commons.compile:
Copy libraries to /MY-WORK/my.commons/dist/lib.
my.commons.jar:
my.data.init:
my.data.deps-jar:
Updating property file: /MY-WORK/my.data.adv/build/built-jar.properties
my.data.compile:
Copy libraries to /MY-WORK/my.data/dist/lib.
my.data.jar:
compile:
compile-test:
test-report:
test:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

**EDIT**

- The project type is "class library", **no** custom configurations in `build.xml` are used.
- Perhaps it is relevant to mention, that the project is old (created with some Netbeans version prior to 6.7).

Comment: What type of project exactly?  (Desktop, Web, other)

Comment: how did you name the class files and where did you put the files?

Comment: Everything is **classic**: JUnit tests are in package folder "test" (label "Test Packages"). JUnit tests are in package, which has same name as that of the classes under test.

Comment: when I have run into this with NB 6.8,it was due to the following reason... The JUnit tests are not in a file named *Test.java.

Comment: @vkraemer: You're right! Please write this as an answer so I can mark it correct! I have found the following in the `build-impl.xml`:
<target depends="init,compile-test,-pre-test-run" if="have.tests" name="-do-test-run"> <j2seproject3:junit testincludes="**/*Test.java"/> </target>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since I submitted the correct clue necessary to generate an answer, I figure that I should add a bit of value to it...

If you create a Java->Class Library project with NetBeans, you can create a unit test associated with each of the classes in your project's Source Packages. You just need to right-click on the class in the Projects explorer.

If you are creating the 'first test' for a project, the IDE lets you choose between JUnit 3 and JUnit 4.

When you create a test for a.b.c.NewClass, NetBeans will allow you to name the test anything you want and put the test in any package you want... most of the time, you do not want to change the defaults that appear in the dialog (a.b.c.NewClassTest).  In NetBeans 6.9 builds, a warning will appear if the name of the test you are about to create does not have "Test" as its suffix.

If you create test class names that do not end with "Test", you can still get them to run when you use the Test action on a project.  You just have to trigger them from a 'normal' test class.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to the user `vkraemer`!

The solution is: Only JUnit tests are run when their name ends with `Test`.

Section from `build-impl.xml` proves it:

```
<target depends="init,compile-test,-pre-test-run"
    if="have.tests" name="-do-test-run">
  <j2seproject3:junit testincludes="**/*Test.java"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using maven, you might want to check your surefire plugin on pom.xml

```
...
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>                        
                </includes>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.config.file>src/test/resources/logging.properties</java.util.logging.config.file>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


  ...
```

Comment: I would agree that this is a pointer into the right direction - also check that maybe there is a parent POM that specifies `<skipTests>true</skipTests>` in its `surefire` plugin configuration

Answer (score 0):

My tests were working then they stopped, just displaying:

> No tests executed.(0.0 s)

The problem was an extra space in the `VM Options:` after the `-D`. This caused problems:

```
-D mysetting.home=something
```

and this fixed it:

```
-Dmysetting.home=something
```